# Azure Easy Tables - Load only one column

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there some way to get only one data column for one row from Azure Easy Tables?

For example Xamarin.Forms app will send name of item to Azure and get the item creation DateTime only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example where we want to select just the `Name` Column from our `Dog` Table.

This sample uses the [Azure Mobile Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client/) and the [Azure Mobile Client SQL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore/) NuGet Packages.

#### Model

```cs
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace SampleApp
{
    public class Dog
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Breed { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [CreatedAt]
        public DateTimeOffset CreatedAt { get; set; }

        [UpdatedAt]
        public DateTimeOffset UpdatedAt { get; set; }

        [Version]
        public string AzureVersion { get; set; }

        [Deleted]
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    }
}
```

#### Logic

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore;

namespace SampleApp
{    
    public class MobileClientService
    {
        bool isMobileClientInitialized;
        MobileServiceClient mobileClient;

        public async Task<string> GetDogName(string id)
        {    
            await InitializeMobileClient(); 

            var dog =  await mobileClient.GetSyncTable<Dog>().LookupAsync(id);
            var dogName = dog.Name;

            return dogName;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetDogNames()
        {    
            await InitializeMobileClient(); 

            var dogNameList =  await mobileClient.GetSyncTable<Dog>().Select(x => x.Name).ToEnumerableAsync();

            return dogNameList;
        }

        async Task InitializeMobileClient()
        {
            if(isMobileClientInitialized)
                return;

            mobileClient = new MobileServiceClient("Your Azure Mobile Client Url");

            var path = Path.Combine(MobileServiceClient.DefaultDatabasePath, "app.db");
            var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore(path);
            store.DefineTable<Dog>();
            //ToDo Define all remaining tables

            await MobileServiceClient.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store, new MobileServiceSyncHandler());

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank this works ! But is it possible to save it to string as text because I want to get only one result and List<string> is returning this :Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.QueryResultList`1[System.String]. A

Comment: Hey @AdamSoták - no problem, I updated the answer! I added the default properties to the Model (these properties automatically added by EasyTables), added a method called GetDogName that returns one column for one row in the Dog table, and fixed a couple typos that may have caused compilation errors. If it works, give the answer an upvote! Much appreciated!

Comment: This works ! Thank you ! I upvoted your answer but my Stack Overflow reputation is under 15 so it won't be displayed.